# Parse.com for iOS : How to make Facebook open-graph calls?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I have integrated ParseFacebookUtilsV4 in my projet.
I successfully used the Facebook login :

```
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let user = user {
        if user.isNew {
            println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
        } else {
            println("User logged in through Facebook!")
        }
    } else {
        println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
    }
}
```

Now I want to make open-graph calls. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the token:

```
NSString *token = [[PFFacebookUtils session] accessToken];
```

And then you can use the token to make open graph calls via [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)